# MVC with AJAX to Remove Table Row

Tags: ajax

I want to Remove a table row in my index page and before removing the row i have to modify in data base and show a pop to confirm the delete action. But while i delete the row it deleted in database but my page is not refreshed after executing the Success action in Ajax. There the code below i write for my view and controller and also giving my definition of model as reference.

```
// Controller
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Entity;
using LAMS_Master.Models;
namespace LAMS_Master.Controllers
{
public class Acquisition_Lease_Case_RecordController : Controller
{
private ApplicationDbContext db;
    public Acquisition_Lease_Case_RecordController()
    {
        db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
    }
    // GET: Acquisition_Lease_Case_Record
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<acquisition_lease_case_record_master> listdata = new List<acquisition_lease_case_record_master>();
        foreach(var d in db.acquisition_lease_case_record_master.Where(c => c.int_deleted_sts == 0).Include(c => c.vill_code).ToList())
        {
            d.chrv_land_class_cd = db.landclasslistmaster.Where(c => c.chrv_landclass_cd == d.chrv_land_class_cd).Select(c => c.chrv_landclass).SingleOrDefault();
            listdata.Add(d);
        }
        return View("Index",listdata);
    }
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.village = new SelectList(db.village_master.Where(c => c.int_deleted_sts == 0).ToList(), "chrv_vill_code", "chrv_vill_name");
        ViewBag.landclass = new SelectList(db.landclasslistmaster.ToList(), "chrv_landclass_cd", "chrv_landclass");
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(acquisition_lease_case_record_master alcrm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            alcrm.fk_chrv_proj_code = "LAMS111811PCB06";
            alcrm.int_created_by = 0;
            alcrm.int_deleted_sts = 0;
            alcrm.chrv_ip_address = UilityMaster.GetLocalIPAddress();
            db.acquisition_lease_case_record_master.Add(alcrm);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.village = new SelectList(db.village_master.Where(c => c.int_deleted_sts == 0).ToList(), "chrv_vill_code", "chrv_vill_name");
        ViewBag.landclass = new SelectList(db.landclasslistmaster.ToList(), "chrv_landclass_cd", "chrv_landclass");
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(string case_no)
    {
        var data = db.acquisition_lease_case_record_master.Include(c=>c.vill_code).Where(c=>c.chrv_case_no==case_no).SingleOrDefault();
        data.chrv_land_class_cd = db.landclasslistmaster.Where(c => c.chrv_landclass_cd == data.chrv_land_class_cd).Select(c => c.chrv_landclass).SingleOrDefault();
        return View("EditALCRM", data);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(acquisition_lease_case_record_master alcrmedit)
    {
        if (alcrmedit.num_case_area!=null && alcrmedit.tms_case_dt!=null && alcrmedit.chrv_case_no!=null)
        {
            var casefromdb = db.acquisition_lease_case_record_master.Find(alcrmedit.chrv_case_no);
            casefromdb.num_case_area = alcrmedit.num_case_area;
            casefromdb.tms_case_dt = alcrmedit.tms_case_dt;
            db.Entry(casefromdb).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }            
        return View("EditALCRM", alcrmedit);
    }
    public JsonResult DeleteCaseRecord(string case_no)
    {
        var deletedata = db.acquisition_lease_case_record_master.Find(case_no);
        bool result = false;
        if (deletedata != null)
        {
            deletedata.int_deleted_sts = 1;
            db.Entry(deletedata).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            result = true;
        }
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
    }
}
```

}

//Index page

```
 @model IEnumerable<LAMS_Master.Models.acquisition_lease_case_record_master> 
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
    <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <h3 class="panel-heading">Case Details</h3>
       <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Village</th>
                        <th>Land Class</th>
                        <th>Case No</th>
                        <th>Case Date</th>
                        <th>Case Area</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var v in Model)
                    {
                        <tr id="@v.chrv_case_no">
                            <td>
                                @v.vill_code.chrv_vill_name
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @v.chrv_land_class_cd
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @v.chrv_case_no
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @v.tms_case_dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @v.num_case_area
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Acquisition_Lease_Case_Record", new { case_no = v.chrv_case_no }, null) |
                                <a href="#" class="deleteLink" onclick="ConfirmDelete('@v.chrv_case_no')">Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddencaseno" value="" />
</div>
@*Modal Defination*@
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Delete</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>Are you sure to delete ?</h4>

                <div style="text-align:center;display:none" id="loaderDiv">
                    <img src="~/Images/loader.gif" width="150" />
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" onclick="DeleteItem()">Confirm</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

// Script for index page

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ConfirmDelete = function (actid) {
        $("#hiddencaseno").val(actid);
        $("#myModal").modal('show');}
var DeleteItem = function () {
    $("#loaderDiv").show();
    var actid = $("#hiddencaseno").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("DeleteCaseRecord")',
        data: { case_no: actid },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#loaderDiv").hide();
            $("#myModal").modal('hide');
            alert('#' + actid);
            $('#'+actid).remove(); }})}
</script>
```